# Redirect from old site and subsites to new domain - main page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following rules in my .htaccess

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^oldname.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newname.com [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.oldname.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.newname.com [r=301,nc]
```

I am wondering how to merge does 2 rules in one. Beside that I would like to redirect if user comes to: www.oldname.com/?action=whatever to newname as well...

Thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?oldname.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newname.com [r=301,nc]
```

change the above code to that

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?oldname.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newname.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

If that not work tell me to give you another solution.

Comment: and what for anything else after this like oldname.com/index.php?action=whatever...

Comment: If the above works for you please rate it and mark it as answer too ! :)

Comment: Hi! That doesn't work... I will try to explain.. I want www.old.com -> www.new.com, old.com -> www.new.com, old.com/index.php -> www.new.com, old.com/whatever -> new.com...

Comment: I have understaint what you want but I try to find the best solution for you ;)

Comment: Sorry :) Not working... When I visit oldname.com I got new page with old name and when i click something i get smth like this: oldname.com/att1/att2/newname.com